# Getting debug information from Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, crash, chromium, debug

How can I actually get a stack trace of why my browser crashed?

All it says is

```
Aw, Snap!
Something went wrong while display this webpage.
```

Comment: [Decoding Crash Dumps](http://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps)

Comment: Beyond the `--debug` option, or you're looking for something to sort through it's output?

Answer (score 0):

David Postill's comment is probably valid above: http://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps, and you can also enable logging to get more info http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging.